# Bitrate over Codec for the best quality?

Tags: audio, video, compression, codec, bitrate

AFAIK **bitrate** means how many bits are used to record the audio/video within one second, while **codec** (or file format) means the compression method to store the clip.

To me, the higher the bitrate, the higher the resolution of the clip, thus the better the quality.

If both codec are lossless compressed, this fact holds.

If one clip with higher bitrate but lossy compressed, while another one with lower bitrate but lossless compressed, we have to consider *how lossy* the compression method is.

For example Clip A with 100kbps lossy compressed, while Clip B with 80kbps lossless compressed. If the lossy compression will loss 10% of details, quality of Clip A will be roughly equal to 90kbps. It means Clip A is still having the better quality.

I am aware of this question because of the [yt-dlp](https://man.archlinux.org/man/yt-dlp.1#Sorting_Formats) default sorting order. I wonder why codec is having a higher priority than bitrate while sorting for the best clip.

> the default order used is: lang,quality,res,fps,hdr:12,**codec**:vp9.2,size,**br**,asr,proto,ext,hasaud,source,id.

For instance, if we pick the Full HD videos (1920x1080 resolution), #248 with 1097kbps vp9 will be sorted more favourable than #137 with 1446kbps avc1. (The list is sorted from worst to best.)

I do not know av codecs well. **I am not concrete sure among #137 vs #248 which one is having the better quality.** But #137 is having 40% higher bitrate, while both avc and vp9 are lossy compressions, I just *think* #137 will probably have better quality than #248.

```
# yt-dlp -v -F -s -e --get-id --get-filename -S res~1080 Bbihv6KKXNY
...
...
ID  EXT   RESOLUTION FPS │   FILESIZE   TBR PROTO │ VCODEC          VBR ACODEC      ABR     ASR MORE INFO
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
...
...
399 mp4   1920x1080   25 │   29.11MiB  927k https │ av01.0.08M.08  927k video only              1080p, mp4_dash
137 mp4   1920x1080   25 │   45.39MiB 1446k https │ avc1.640028   1446k video only              1080p, mp4_dash
248 webm  1920x1080   25 │   34.45MiB 1097k https │ vp9           1097k video only              1080p, webm_dash
```

Why yt-dlp prioritise codec over bitrate? When we choose the best quality audio/video, should we sort by bitrate or codec?

Comment: Newer codecs may have better algorithms that can reproduce images or motion better than older codecs. It is possible that a newer and better codec could produce a higher quality video with lower bitrate but higher cost for CPU or GPU power. Pure bitrate is not a valid indicator of "best" quality.

Comment: @FrankThomas - It is not only for grouping and sorting. It actually controls which source to download.

Comment: @Mokubai - Good to know this. With this fact, codec might be a more deterministic factor than bitrate on quality.

Comment: Also in the case of lossless codec, a compressed stream with higher bitrate does NOT signify better quality. For example, when compressing the same PCM stream to FLAC, the bitrate gets lower if you specify a higher compression level, but after decoding/decompression, you get the same PCM stream -- that is the meaning of lossless.

Comment: @TomYan - This is the thing actually confuses me. The bitrate, let's say 100kbps of FLAC, means using 100kb per second on the FLAC file, or regarding the uncompressed WAV file? If the former is true, 100kbps FLAC should have the same file size as 100kbps MP3. If the later is true, lowering the bitrate of FLAC means lowering the bitrate of the uncompressed WAV too. This action should be lossy.

Comment: The former is true. The unit Kbps means that when the value times the audio length in second and divided by 8 (1 byte = 8 bit), you get the file size in kilobyte regardless of the codec. Note that the bitrate we are talking about here is the statistical / average bitrate of the compressed stream (the reverse of the calculation I just mentioned) though. Also note that in the case of lossless compression, you can't specify the bitrate you desire like in the case of lossy. You can only specify a value to signify "how hard" the codec should try to get the file size smaller / bitrate lower.

Comment: To make it clearer, you can also see it like input bitrate vs output bitrate, where input/output refers to what gets into and out of the *decoder*. What I/we've been talking about so far is the input bitrate, whereas the output bitrate is the same as the original PCM stream that got compressed in the first place (since the output should be *identical* to that in the case of lossless). On the other hand, output bitrate in the lossy case is usually sample rate *  number of channel * 16 or 32, depending on whether the decoder is asked / designed to decode to 16-bit fixed-point or 32-bit float PCM

Comment: @TomYan - Thanks a lot. I learnt a lot. With your info, I am quite sure the codec determines the output quality in most cases. Usually the source uncompressed stream is identical. A better codec render less loss during compression and decompression. The bitrate of the compressed file does not matter much (except if it is too much over compressed). It is because the decompressed **output** stream is the one which determines the quality.